# Screen Flow Empty/Null values

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, flowscreen

I have screen flow with two number fields and a display text field. When user enters numbers then I wanted to do a some math and display the value using display text field. I created a formula using the two number fields however the values are always null/empty  on the same screen and the display text does not display anything and could not figure out why. However if I add another screen(Say screen2) and navigate to it from the screen that collets user input, The formula is working and I see the result in display text but my goal is to display it on the same screen. Not sure why we can't use field values in the same screen.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible on the same screen, you have to do it the way you did it. Consider using a lightning aura component.

Comment: If you were doing this in a VFP, you would make a component that refreshes when you click a button or enter. Unfortunately Flow doesn't have anything like that. The best thing you could do it click next to go to another screen and show the results.

Answer (score 1):

After entering the inputs, onClick of Next button try to validate the result through a decision block and loop it back to the same screen and add the formula field through a display text element.